# Measuring MOSFET input capacitance?

Tags: mosfet, capacitance, charge

Am I calculating total input capacitance or gate capacitance or none of the above? And are my calculations even correct to begin with. The point of this is that I want to know what gate capacitance im dealing with to properly chose a gate resistor to give me the rise time I need, more or less.

So I have the following circuit using the old [IRF540](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91021/91021.pdf)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQeuEN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am probing the gate directly and get the following readings:

[image]

I am loosing 500 mV somewhere but anyways:

My voltage at 1 time constant is:
(This is where the dashed vertical line is)

[image: 1t]

So measuring the time from 0 V (solid vertical line) to the 1 time constant line (dashed) you can see is about 530 ns. So my time constant is 530 ns and the gate resistor is 100 ohm then:

[image]

Is my logic correct that this is my input capacitance? And given will this vary if I have same Vds but a Vgs that is NOT equal to Vds?

Extra points: Where are my 500 mV?

Comment: I have gone back to the bench and calculated a time constant of 100nS given this capacitance and found that I need a resistor of 18ohms or so, this will get me 7.2V in 100nS, and it works give or take a few nano seconds...I guess now I need to change Vds and see how this affects this capacitance value

Comment: S for Siemens. s for second.

Comment: Your calculations are only valid for a fast enough switch

Comment: I used a similar circuit , but with an 82K instead of 100R, and I found that with an IRF640 , the gate capacitance increased with gate voltage , but I suspect , it may have been some sort of oscillation .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are measuring the lump capacitance in accord with this [standard model](https://www.nutsvolts.com/questions-and-answers/mosfet-basics),

[image]

You even have observed the Miller Plateau.

The capacitances do depend on applied voltages however, see [this ROHM article](https://www.rohm.com/electronics-basics/transistors/understanding-mosfet-characteristics). As VDS increases the capacitance decreases.

Brief description of methods used to characterize individual capacitances can be found in this Vishay Siliconix [appnote AN-957](https://www.vishay.com/docs/90715/an957.pdf), see Fig.17, 18, and 19. Three configurations of a capacitance bridge are used, and then individual caps are algebraically determined.

Comment: that is a great App note you linked. Thanks A lot!